# How to fix 'BadServiceUnsupported' error when trying to get historic data from Opc Server

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I'am trying to get historic data for a tag from an opc server, but I am getting 'BadServiceUnsupported' error. I already configured the Opc Server and the Local historian for a specific tag in KepserverEX V6.

I am using this opc library https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard.

I successfully read tag values, but I have issues with historic data, exactly when the HistoryRead method is called:

`m_Session.HistoryRead(
    null,
    new ExtensionObject(details),
    TimestampsToReturn.Source,
    false,
    nodesToRead,
    out results,
    out diagnosticInfos);`

getting 'BadServiceUnsupported' exception.

I also enabled HDA connection on project settings in KepserverEx, but it seems it didn't solve the issue.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to be fixed in this case. Kepserver only supports HDA from OPC Classic (COM/DCOM), not OPC UA.

Answer (score 1):

To workaround this, you can run the OPC UA Wrapper Server: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/master/ComIOP/README.md

The Wrapper Server will be the bridge between your application and KepServerEX. It goes like this:

```
[Your Application] --- (OPC-UA) ---> [OPC UA Wrapper Server] --- (OPC-HDA) ---> [KepServerEX]
```

I've tested the above scenario, using `m_Session.HistoryRead()` I can successfully read historical values from KepServerEX v6.6

For the Server Wrapper to open HDA connection to KepServerEX, open `Opc.Ua.ComServerWrapper.Config.xml` and enable the `ComClientConfiguration` for HDA. It should look something like this:

```
<ComClientConfiguration i:type="ComHdaClientConfiguration">
    <ServerUrl>opc.com://localhost/Kepware.KEPServerEX_HDA.V6/{5C905440-YOUR_CLSID_HERE}</ServerUrl>
    <ServerName>HDA</ServerName>
    <MaxReconnectWait>10000</MaxReconnectWait>
    <SeperatorChars></SeperatorChars>
    <AddCapabilitiesToServerObject>true</AddCapabilitiesToServerObject>
    <AttributeSamplingInterval>1000</AttributeSamplingInterval>
    <TreatUncertainAsBad>true</TreatUncertainAsBad>
    <PercentDataBad>0</PercentDataBad>
    <PercentDataGood>100</PercentDataGood>
    <SteppedSlopedExtrapolation>false</SteppedSlopedExtrapolation>
</ComClientConfiguration>
```